# What is the Difference in the Big-Oh of these Loops?

Tags: time-complexity

The Three For Loops:

[image: Three for loops]

I'm fairly new to this Big-Oh stuff and I'm having difficulty seeing the difference in complexity between these three loops.

They all seem to run less than O(n^2) but more than O(n).

Could someone explain to me how to evaluate the complexity of these loops?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can (1) post the text of the code you're confused about, and (2) ask a question. You said you're confused, you said you don't know the difference between some things; those are facts, not questions. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I made a few changes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me how the evaluate to complexity of these loops?

Start by clearly defining the problem. The linked image has little to go on, so let's start making up stuff:

- The parameter being varied is integer n.
- C is a constant positive integer value greater than one.
- the loop variables are integers
- integers do not overflow
- The costs of addition, comparison, assignment, multiplication and indexing is all constant.
- The cost we are looking to find the complexity of is the cost of the constant operations of the innermost loop; we ignore all the additions and whatnot in the actual computations of the loop variables.
- In each case the innermost statement is the same, and is of constant cost, so let's just call that cost "one unit" of cost.

Great.

What is the cost of the first loop?

The cost of the inner statement is one unit.

The cost of the "j" loop containing it is ten units every time.

How many times does the "i" loop run?  Roughly n divided by C times.

So the total cost of the "i" loop is 10 * n / C, which is O(n).

Now can you do the second and third loops?  Say more clearly where you are running into trouble.  Start with:

- The cost of the first run of the "j" loop is 1 unit.
- The cost of the second run of the "j" loop is C units
- The cost of the third run of the "j" loop is C * C units
- ...

and go from there.

Remember that you don't need to work out the *exact* cost function. You just need to figure out the *dominating* cost. Hint: what do we know about C * C * C ... at the *last* run of the outer loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can analyse the loops using Sigma notation. Note that for the purpose of studying the asymptotic behaviour of loop (a), the constant `C` just describes the linear increment in the loop, and we can freely choose any value of `C` in our analysis (since the inner loop is just a fixed number of iterations) however assuming `C>0` (integer). Hence, for loop (a), choose `C=1`. For loop (b), we'll include C, and assume, however, that `C > 1` (integer). If `C = 1` in loop (b), it will never terminate as `i` is never incremented. Finally define the innermost operations in all loops as our *basic operations*, with cost `O(1)`.

The Sigma notation analysis follows:

[image: Sigma notation]

Hence

```
(a) is O(n)
(b) is O(n)
(c) is O(n*log(n))
```